# Load html file from a framework is this possible?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Hi I want to load html and .js file from my project. These are the below steps i am following to load html file through framework but i am not able to hit html files.

Steps followed.

Created a framework which has webview as subview in it.

Created Resource.bundle and added all my html,.js files and images in the bundle.

When i add this framework into my project and try to access the image from the bundle i am not able to.
when i try to hit the html file i am not able to laod the html file in my webview.

```
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Resource" ofType:@"bundle"];
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] pathForResource:@"simple" ofType:@"html"];

    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSURL *url=[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
    [webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:url];
    [self addSubview:webview];
```

Can anyone tell me why this wont work and is this the right approach to follow?

Comment: Try this [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" 
                                                                                                         ofType:@"html"]
                                                             isDirectory:NO]]];

Comment: Did you confirm the resources are actually in the bundle? Check your build products and open the bundle using Finder.

Comment: @Joris Kluivers yes resources are in the bundle...

Answer (score 0):

I create a bundle with index.html that call a js with a simple alert, with this code i'm able to se the alert

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BundleName" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[_web loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

the html work in local? the webview is initialized?

Comment: yes the html works in local and webview is initialized...I tried above code and its not working...